# Make OpenGL game perform better

Tags: opengl, performance

I have programmed an OpenGL game which just contains one F1 car and a track. It is very simple and only uses around of 10'000 - 20'000 triangles. It should run on any PC but it won't, it needs a really good graphics-card to run at a decent framerate. Can you write some methods or links to sites which would help me make my scene/game more efective?

my game can be downloaded from [here](http://wblade.com)

or directly from [here](http://wblade.com/ogl/opnegl.zip)

Comment: Did you compile that as debug or release build?

Comment: compile and debug it works but i m using glut.h, and glaux.h if it falls it is because you have to have them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I have seen, you are using Display lists. They are already few years depricated and you should use vertex buffer objects. It maybe could help.

They work on this princip: You create buffer in graphics memory. Still in init phase you copy your data there (vertex coordinates, texture coordinates, normals etc.). And always in display function just use these data to render all geometry. It's fast and most used in these days (I hope).

Comment: If you don't know, how to use Vertex buffer object (VBO), you can follow these steps: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html

Comment: Ok thanks all of you I will check out the debuger and corect to vertex buffer object

Answer (score 2):

Go grab [gDEBugger](http://www.gremedy.com/). It's free for everyone now - you just need to register to get a free 1-year license.

With it, you can check if you're fill bound, vertex processing bound, shader bound or cpu bound - as well as check if you're doing something stupid like rendering 10000 separate objects.